# Is it more efficient to fetch all DB rows at once in an array then parse or just parse each row?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, apache

When dealing with huge number of MySQL entries, is it more efficient to fetch them all at once in a PHP array or parse each row in a while fetch_assoc loop? I'm talking about hundreds of thousands of records that will grow into millions and, before I actually go about optimizing the DB, I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way to parse MySQL data with PHP. The parsing involves several validations and formatting before assigning to another array for inserting / updating another MySQL DB.

Hope this makes sense. Your views and suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Is a general question, depend in some case is better a php parse in other the select. You must refer to a specific case..

Comment: Large numbers of array entries requires large amounts of memory, with a big overhead in allocation and later in deallocation..... so it's generally more efficient processing each database record individually where possible to avoid this

Comment: It very much depends on what you're doing with it. If you can limit what you pull out from MySQL you'll remove the biggest bottleneck.

Comment: efficient in what respect? Reading to a large array might be faster, but will consume more memory.

Comment: Generally I build pagination into systems that need to do deal with very large data-sets; pagination is more than a GUI element, it's often a performance solution as well. Like I said, shrink how much data you pull out of MySQL and you likely won't have to worry about the rest of the approach.

Comment: Basically there's this PHP cronjob that syncs two different environments: pulls some data from one server and prepares it (insert & update) for a MySQL DB. Currently the script take a few good hours to complete and uses quite a large amount of memory and I need to cut down on execution time as well as resource usage. Should I run the validations / parsing within the fetch loop and insert / update each row as I go along, or fetch them all at once in an array, run the validations on the array elements, then do the insert / updates in batches?

Comment: I get what you're saying  thelastshadow, that's a very good point actually. Thing is I only get a not too generous window to do this, thought so far it's been enough.  Is there a way that you could pull from MySQL in parallel / simultaneous threads? :-/

Comment: On top of what's already been said (about pagination also), is to query only the columns needed `SELECT col1, col2` rather than all the columns `SELECT *` if you have many. Making sure that the database is properly indexed will offer better performance. Using LIMIT is also another option.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. What I take from this is that I need to balance between execution time and memory usage while optimizing the source DB. I really appreciate all your insights. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your implementation and hardware limits:

Scenario 1 - If memory is a bottleneck, you should fetch one at a time.

Scenario 2 - If you do not want to hold the connection and transactions waiting, I would flush everything to an array and then do whatever calculations and validations that need to be made.

... Scenario N ...

In my opinion it is hard to provide an answer that fits all scenarios.

PS: As per your comments, you should avoid inserting one row at a time, inserting in batches saves a lot of time.